# How to set only specific values for a parameter in docopt python?

Tags: python, docopt

I am trying to use docopt for a python code. I actually need to set only specific values for a parameter. My usage is as below:

```
"""
Usage:
test.py --list=(all|available)

Options:
    list    Choice to list devices (all / available)
"""
```

I've tried to run it as: `python test.py --list=all` but it doesn't accept the value and just displays the docopt string .

I want the value of list parameter to be either 'all' or 'available'. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: as of today this isn't possible using docopt syntax, see discussion here https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example to achieve what you want:

**test.py:**

```
"""
Usage:
  test.py list (all|available)

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  --version     Show version.

  list          Choice to list devices (all / available)
"""
from docopt import docopt

def list_devices(all_devices=True):
    if all_devices:
        print("Listing all devices...")
    else:
        print("Listing available devices...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='test 1.0')

    if arguments["list"]:
        list_devices(arguments["all"])
```

With this script you could run statements like:

```
python test.py list all
```

or:

```
python test.py list available
```